# Dynamic mutation in vue3 with vuex and typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

I have an Module in store which saves up some filtering of the application. I will paste a small part of the interface:

```
export interface Filters {
    searchFields: string[];
    division: string;
    subDivision: string[];
}
```

With this interface I have created a Module in store:

```
const filtersModule: Module<Filters, any> = {
    state: {
        searchFields: [...DEFAULT_SEARCH_FIELDS],
        division: "",
        subDivision: [],
    }
    getters: {
        getSearchFields: (state) => (state.searchFields),
        getDivision: (state) => (state.division),
        getSubDivision: (state) => (state.subDivision)
    }
    acctions: {
        ...
    },
    mutations: {
        emptyFilters: (state: Filters, filterNames: string[]) => {
            filterNames.forEach(filterName => {
                state[filterName] = helpers.getDefaultValueForFilterType(state[filterName])
                }
            })
    }
```

I have the following error error while I am doing this

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Filters'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Filters'.
```

What should be the appropriate way to define the interface or just the store in order to call dynamically state properties?